# SQL Server: how to update rows with additional information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation in which a table has information like:

```
First Name | Last Name |  Email
-----------+-----------+-----------------
John          Doe         jd@email.com
Jane          Dont        jnd@email.com
```

And I have a user who wants their email added on to *both* row's emails to looks like:

```
First Name | Last Name |  Email
-----------+-----------+-----------------------------
John          Doe         jd@email.com;a@email.com
Jane          Dont        jnd@email.com;a@email.com
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: with what you are asking i think you would be better off with another table for the emails ex:Email_Adresses with 2 columns,one as the foreign key and the other column as the email adress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add `a@email.com` to all rows in your table:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Email = Email + ';a@email.com'
```

To update certain rows:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Email = t.Email + ';a@email.com'
FROM Table t
WHERE t.FirstName = 'John'
```

Note: the above query will update all records with the first name of `John`

**Edit** ******** Per @destination-data comment:

If you are also trying to add the new email to columns that have `NULL` value

```
SET Email = ISNULL(Email, '') + ';a@email.com'
```

"...Because null plus anything is null." This technique will change the value from `NULL` to an empty string plus the new value.

Comment: Thank bjones, I will need to update all rows. Just to be sure for this line SET Email = Email + ';a@email.com' the = Email is equivalent to = column_name + 'additional email address' correct?

Comment: @ttham - The `=Email` is equivalent to `= 'EmailValueInThisRow' + 'additional'`

Comment: Yes I'm just wondering if the query is like SET column_name = column_name + 'newemail'

Comment: @ttham Yes. You will use the column name + the new value you want to add

Comment: @ttham Glad I could help. Feel free to mark it as the answer for others that may come across with a similar question.

Comment: If the column `Email` allows nulls use `SET Email = ISNULL(Email, '') + ';a@email.com'`.  Why?  Because null plus anything is null.  Would also recommend you consider @terrybozzio's suggestion.  Future updates and searches will be complicated by allowing one cell to contain multiple values.

Comment: @destination-data good point. Updated answer to include your suggestion.